# When running servlet in tomcat 7 throws FileNotFoundException (permission denied)

Tags: apache, servlets, tomcat7

When running the servlet application, certain files are written to the application folder, during that time the server throws

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.dbf.0 (Permission denied)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:101)
at jdbm.recman.RecordFile.getRaf(RecordFile.java:125)
at jdbm.recman.RecordFile.<init>(RecordFile.java:104)
```

i am trying to run it on mac os x, and also permission have been provided to write in the catalina.policy file. and also tried to give the system access permission for the file with 755,777 using chmod. Is it the problem related to the os or is it related to file permission scheme in the catalina.policy file?, i am not getting any security exception

whenever i try it on the windows platform its running fine, but when i run it on mac or unix based systems its throwing this exception, the problem is a small db called pcdb is created once the war file is deployed, so problems exisiting while creating the db files itself, these db files are small chunks of about 8 files

Comment: Well the exception says that the file is not found, nothing to do with read/write permissions. Please check that the file exists in the correct location. Maybe if you provide some more info, you can get better help with this. This exception will be thrown by the FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and RandomAccessFile constructors when a file with the specified pathname does not exist.It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing.

Comment: i am using pcdb a small database file,which will be created when a war file is deployed to apache tomcat, now the case is whenever it is trying to write these file onto the server for the first time this exceptions is thrown. The files will be created by the pcdb itself and it consists of small chunks of 8 files.

Comment: so you have problem reading these 8 files? Please also update your question with this info

Comment: whenever i try it on the windows platform its running fine, but when i  run it on mac or unix based systems its throwing this exception

Comment: As I looked more closely the code, that generates the exception, this jdbm function tries to lock a RAF so that it can read it. When this code executes, `ret = new RandomAccessFile(name, "rw");` the FileNotFoundException is thrown.

Comment: Based on the constructor documentation of the RAF, `FileNotFoundException - if the mode is "r" but the given string does not denote an existing regular file, or if the mode begins with "rw" but the given string does not denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or creating the file `

Comment: so my doubt is then how come it works on windows machine, whereas it doesnt work on a mac system

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23758/discussion-between-mavroscy-and-raghul)